# Laravel in a subfolder and pagination

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, pagination, subdirectory

I've my Laravel project in a sub (sub) folder from my root folder and am using the simplePaginate() method in some views. After a little search I've noticted the `AbstractPaginator` is used and provides a method `url()` which is somewhere down the road invoked by the `BootstrapThreeNextPreviousButtonRendererTrait` which gets called from `SimpleBootstrapThreePresenter`.

I've been searching in the my `config/app.php` and `helpers.php` file to find something pointing to a solution. But haven't found anything yet.

How can I set up Laravel (5.1) to use my subfolder structure with the pagination class?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it modifying the `BootstrapThreeNextPreviousButtonRendererTrait`. I'm aware I could have also modified the `AbstractPaginator` but since I'm not overseeing the consequences of that right now I've chosen to tailor the trait to my needs, like so:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Pagination;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

trait BootstrapThreeNextPreviousButtonRendererTrait
{
    /**
     * Get the previous page pagination element.
     *
     * @param  string  $text
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPreviousButton($text = '&laquo;')
    {
        // If the current page is less than or equal to one, it means we can't go any
        // further back in the pages, so we will render a disabled previous button
        // when that is the case. Otherwise, we will give it an active "status".
        if ($this->paginator->currentPage() <= 1) {
            return $this->getDisabledTextWrapper($text);
        }

        $url = url() . '/' . Request::path() . '?page=' . ($this->paginator->currentPage() - 1);
        //Laravel shipped code disabled because of an installation in a sub-sub folder.
        //$url = $this->paginator->url(
        //    $this->paginator->currentPage() - 1
        //);

        return $this->getPageLinkWrapper($url, $text, 'prev');
    }

    /**
     * Get the next page pagination element.
     *
     * @param  string  $text
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNextButton($text = '&raquo;')
    {
        // If the current page is greater than or equal to the last page, it means we
        // can't go any further into the pages, as we're already on this last page
        // that is available, so we will make it the "next" link style disabled.
        if (! $this->paginator->hasMorePages()) {
            return $this->getDisabledTextWrapper($text);
        }

        $url = url() . '/' . Request::path() . '?page=' . ($this->paginator->currentPage() + 1);
        //Laravel shipped code disabled because of an installation in a sub-sub folder.
        //$url = $this->paginator->url($this->paginator->currentPage() + 1);

        return $this->getPageLinkWrapper($url, $text, 'next');
    }
}
```